# RxJS: TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am trying to create a live search from a local array variable(so not over network, I am already getting data and storing it on launch) using RxJS, here is what the array I am searching from looks like

```
[
        {
            "userId": 6130,
            "friendId": 426,
            "firstName": "hardik",
            "lastName": "sa123",
            "userName": "hardiksa123",
            "image": "somelink",
            "thumbs": [
                {
                    "path": "somelink",
                    "size": "original"
                },
                {
                    "path": "somelink",
                    "size": "thumb_300x300"
                }
            ],
            "isBlocked": 0
        },
        {
            "userId": 6130,
            "friendId": 78294,
            "firstName": "mayank",
            "lastName": "vyas",
            "userName": "mayank123",
            "image": "",
            "thumbs": [],
            "isBlocked": 0
        },
        {
            "userId": 6130,
            "friendId": 941,
            "firstName": "Sagar",
            "lastName": "Sa",
            "userName": "sagar",
            "image": "",
            "thumbs": [],
            "isBlocked": 0
        }
    ]
```

Here is the component code

```
    const friendsFiltered = (friendList) => this.searchedFriends = friendList;

    const getFullName = (friend) =>
      `${friend.firstName} ${friend.lastName}`;

    const isFriendMatching = (friend, searchText) =>
      getFullName(friend).startsWith(searchText.toLowerCase());

    const getMatchingFriends = (searchText) =>
      of(this.allFriends.filter(friend => isFriendMatching(friend, searchText)));

    console.log(getMatchingFriends);

    this.nameSearch$ = this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      map(searchText => searchText.trim()),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(searchText => searchText.length),
      tap(c => console.log('search', c)),
      switchMap(getMatchingFriends)
    );

    this.nameSearch$.subscribe(friendsFiltered);
```

If I remove the `switchMap` from the pipe it works fine and the error falls the the `getMatchingFriends` method itself

**Note:** There is a question with the exact same title but the content inside is completely different, so please take note of that.

**EDIT**
This is what the entire code looks like after update one

```
  searchForn: FormGroup;
  allFriends;
  nameSearch$: Observable<any>;
  searchedFriends: any[] = [];
  constructor(
    private friendService: FriendService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialiseForm();
    this.nameSearch$ = this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      map(searchText => searchText.trim()),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(searchText => searchText.length),
      tap(c => console.log('search', c)),
      switchMap(this.getMatchingFriends)
    );

    this.nameSearch$.subscribe(this.friendsFiltered);
  }

  initialiseForm() {
    this.searchForn = this.fb.group({
      searchName: [],
    });
  }

  get search() { return this.searchForn.get('searchName'); }

  friendsFiltered = (friendList) => {
    this.searchedFriends = friendList;
    console.log('sf', this.searchedFriends);
  }

  getFullName = (friend) => `${friend.firstName.toLowerCase()} ${friend.lastName.toLowerCase()}`;

  isFriendMatching = (friend, searchText) =>
    this.getFullName(friend).includes(searchText.toLowerCase());

  getMatchingFriends = (searchText) =>
    of(this.allFriends.filter(friend => this.isFriendMatching(friend, searchText)));

  getAllFriends() {
    this.friendService.getFriends().then((friends: any) => {
      this.allFriends = friends.friends;
    }).catch((err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try map(getMatchingFriends) instead of switchMap(getMatchingFriends)

Comment: @ShalomPeles then nothing sort of happens, I think I need switchMap since it'll subscribe to getMatchingFriends and return the result of it

Comment: Seems to be working without error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpcns3 . Where are these methods located? I see you reference `this` in the various methods, but you are using `const`. Are these methods in an @Injectable() or @Component() class? You may need to share more code or fork that example to provide a complete picture of your code/issue.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I update the question with full code, previously all the methods were within a watchSearch() method that I was calling on Init now after referencing the stackblitz you posted I've moved it to global scope and moved subscribing to ngOninit, unfortunately still getting the error

Comment: Any reason why you use observable if your data is local?
that not a good idea, and I cant seem to see ANY reason to do it.

Comment: @Talg123Currently the implementation is like that because I am waiting on some work from others, later I might have to get data from an api before making search, also I'm trying to learn RxJS

Comment: (can't edit comment) I removed the api calls from the full code above, but rest assured I am making sure I have the data to search from in the manner as shown at the beginning of OP

Comment: Ok found the problem, it was stupid and was with how I was importing, I was doing or rather VSCode autoImported ```import { of } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of'```, Instead of  ```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';``` . After seeing the stackblitz I have now corrected that mistake and it's working now, thanks for help!